# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajax'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, methods, typeerror

I'm getting the following error in my console when I try to initialize the quoteResults Javascript function on my Wordpress site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajax'
```

I have used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(quoteResults);
```

to call the quoteResults function and it works totally fine.  However, as soon as I try to trigger it using another method it fails (I tried .click also, same problem).

```
jQuery( '#filter input' ).change(quoteResults);
function quoteResults($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/api/json.file.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { }
    });
};
```

Comment: What is `$` refering to? See using: jQuery instead

Comment: console.log($) will show you why it does not work. $ would be an event object, not a jQuery object. It is not like ready.

Comment: WHy did you make your own wrong `$`?

Comment: I implemented $ improperly thinking I could use it that way to avoid changing $ to jQuery inside the function.  My bad.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$` parameter,

```
 function quoteResults() {
```

OR

use `jQuery` in place of `$`, like

```
jQuery.ajax({
```

Comment: I removed the $ parameter and I'm now getting this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined

Comment: @DEUTSCHWULF, use `jQuery` in place of `$`, like `jQuery.ajax`

Comment: Wow, replacing $ with jQuery worked.  I'd thought that using the $ parameter would do the same thing.  Thank you!